# Simplifying Big O

Tags: big-o, pseudocode

```
// Assume n is some random integer
int q = 1;
while (q <= Math.Sqrt(n))
{
   q++;
   int k = 1;
   while (k <= Math.Log(n, 2))
   {
       k++;
       if (q^k == n){
          return true;
   }
}
return false;
```

In this code above, I'm finding it very difficult to decide what the Big O would be for the worst case. Since the loop runs N times with a nested loop that runs log2(N) times I know it should be O(sqrt(n)*log2(n)) times. However, I find it very confusing as to how it's suppose to be simplified. I understand that sqrt(n) grows faster but I'm unsure if I can disregard log2(n) since it's being multiplied. If I'm not disregarding log2(n), I'm not sure if it should be n^2 since it's two terms of n being multiplied, or if I should leave it as it is.

Comment: No, you cannot disregard a non-constant multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Take it simple, think that the extern while loop is executed sqrt(n) times and that inside there is another while loop that is executed log2(n) times and inside it assume that all operations take O(1) time to being executed.
So we have a while loop executed sqrt(n) times and an operation inside it that take O(log2(n)) to being executed (that is the other while loop, think of it as a black box pf which you know the asymptotic running time). Therefore the complexity of the algorithm is O(sqrt(n)log2(n)).

Comment: The OP states this conclusion in the question. The OP then asks how to _simplify_ that conclusion. Are you saying there is no simplification?

Comment: The OP is confused on how to do the analysis so I explain it as simply as possible to try to clear its doubts

Comment: You conclude "Therefore the complexity of the algorithm is O(sqrt(n)log2(n))." But the OP says "I know it should be O(sqrt(n)*log2(n))". The OP then asks "I'm unsure if I can disregard log2(n) since it's being multiplied". That is the question to answer.